# Getting Data from my Web-Service using proxy:Rest from Sencha Touch 2

Tags: rest, sencha-touch-2

While using this code, i can't get any results...

```
Ext.define('Teste.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',
initialize: function(){    
    Ext.define('User', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model', 
       config: {  
            fields: ['description', 'discountCode' , 'prodCode'],
            proxy: {
                type: 'rest',
                format:'json',
                url : 'http://localhost:8080/stcws/resources/com.database.productcode/'
            }     
        }    
    });     
    var store = new Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {     
        model: 'User'  
    }); 
    store.load();
    console.log(store.getCount());   
}});
```

But if i take out

```
format:'json',
```

I get a XML response, what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the 'Rest' proxy and get a Json response we just need to add to the Proxy:

```
headers: {                
    'Accept' : 'application/json'                 
},
```

And take out...

```
format:'json',
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Json Reader to read server response.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json

**Try:**

```
proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'users.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
```

or

```
 proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url : 'users.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json'
                model: 'User'
            }
        }
```

Comment: I got it! We just need to add to the proxy... `headers:{'Accept':'application/json'}`.